# 503 error on neo4j ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j

I have installed neo4j on an aws ec2 ubuntu instance and changed the password. From a remote machine I can

```
rhys@coconut:~$ curl -u neo4j:password http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7474
{
  "management" : "http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7474/db/manage/",
  "data" : "http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7474/db/data/"
}
```

Going to 
`http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7474/db/data/` with `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false` produces a 503 error;

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /browser/. Reason:

    Service Unavailable

Powered by Jetty://
```

How can I access the neo4j browser securely and without getting a 503 error?

Answer (score 0):

Remote access to the browser is disabled by default.

Make sure to uncomment the following line in your `neo4j-server.properties` file :

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that, this line has been uncommented.